# What are all the sub-domain of stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Today searching for `jquery dynatree slow in IE` lead to a result from http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/. Checking further, this has all the facebook posts.

So, are there such more sub-domains? First I thought the top tags would be having this feature, just doesn't seems to be there as I tried http://java.stackoverflow.com which is not present.

I also envisaged that this might the featured/sponsored tag that get the sub-domain, but even that is not the case as per my observation for another sponsored tag `android` (http://android.stackoverflow.com).

I have been here for a year and never came across this site. I also don't see a link to this anywhere or a relevant blog post for this.

Would be great if someone could throw some light on this.

Answer (score 5):

No, facebook.SO is the only one. It's due to [the collaboration between SO and Facebook to create a better environment for FB API devs.](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/545/)

However, there are a lot of other [stackexchange subdomain sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic) (including android.SE, but that's not about android coding). These are separate sites (unlike facebook.SO, which is just a tag-filtered version of Stack Overflow)